# PHP Image Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am trying to make this .php file act as a .png, so I can do e.g. `<img src='test.php'>` [example]

I added a header as an image and did this:

```
<?php

/* Start Connection */
[Ignore This]
/* End Connection */

/* Add to counter */
mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET counter = counter + 1");
/* End Add */

/* For Echo */
$count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM counter"));
$hits = $count[0];
/* Create Echo as Null 
* @echo
echo "$hits";
*/

/* End Echo */

//Img Area
$font = "font.ttf";
$image = imagecreatefrompng("hits.png");
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 10, 24, $color, $font, $hits);
imagepng($image, "test.png");
imagedestroy($image);
header('Content-Type: image/png')
?>
```

But it just displays a broken image.

This file is img.php

The broken image is img.php

How can I fix this?

Comment: For what it's worth, mysql_* should typically be avoided in new code in favour of PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imagepng($image, "test.png");` if you're saving the image to a file, why are you expecting it to be output to the browser?  If you want it to be output directly, just use `imagepng($image);`

Also, the header call needs to be before anything is output.

Comment: If I do imagepng($image); it gives me an error.  The hit counter then does not function correctly failing to add hits.

Comment: @ClubpenguinIcebox Then what is that error?  I would try to get the image an the DB stuff working separately and then reconnect them.  In other words, try commenting out all of the DB stuff and hard coding `$hits = 55;`.  Then see if the image renders correctly.  If not, get the image to work.  Once the image works, then try adding back in the DB stuff.

Comment: It expects paremeter 1 to be a resource, and it says a boolean was given.  And I understand hits=55 will work, I wan't this code to be an image though

Comment: @ClubpenguinIcebox That means the query is failing for some reason or other.  Try checking what mysql_error() says.